# TCP multi threading web server in python

Tags: python, multithreading, tcp

I have created a TCP multithreading webserver but it gives me the following 
**If the file is found** 
1. It says "int obj has no attribute encode"
2. Later, it will show list index out of range

**If the file is not found** 
1. It does not display the html error message on the web browser
2. Later, it will show list index out of range

My server code is

```
import socket
import threading
import os
import sys

#to convert bytes into string 
def bytestoString(stringToRead):
        stringToRead = bytes.decode(stringToRead)
        type(stringToRead)
        return(stringToRead)

#to conver string into bytes
def stringToBytes(bytesToSend1):
        bytesToSend1= str.encode(bytesToSend1)
        type (bytes)
        return(bytesToSend1)
#to retreive a file
def retrFile(name,sock):
    message=sock.recv(1024)
    message_string = bytestoString(message)
    print(message_string)
    fileName=message_string.split()[1]
    fileName=fileName.split("/")[1]
    #stringLength=len(fileName)
    print(fileName)

    if os.path.isfile(fileName):
        print ('Ready to send the file................')
        with open(fileName,'rb') as fileRead:
            data= fileRead.read()
            print (data)
            exists_Bytes=stringToBytes('HTTP/1.1 200 OK\nContent-type=text/html')
            sock.send(exists_Bytes)
            for i in range(0 ,len(data)): 
                sock.send((data[i]).encode())
            print('file sent succesfully')
            sock.close()
    else :
        httpResponse=stringToBytes('HTTP/1.1 404 not Found')
        sock.send(httpResponse)
        #errorDisplayPage=stringToBytes('<html><title>404 Error</title><body>404 Error- Page cannot be found </body></html>')
        sock.send(b'<html><title>404 Error</title><body>404 Error- Page cannot be found </body></html>')
        print ('error message displayed')  
        sock.close()


def Main(serverPort):
    #creating a server socket type TCP
    serverSocket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    localHost=socket.gethostname()
    #binding the server to the client
    serverSocket.bind((localHost,serverPort))

    serverSocket.listen(5)

    print ('***Server is ready to recieve***')

    while True:

        connectionSocket, addr = serverSocket.accept()
        print ('got connection from:<', addr,'>')
        t=threading.Thread(target=retrFile,args=('retrThread',connectionSocket))
        t.start()
    connectionSocket.send('thank you for connecting')
    connectionSocket.close()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    #getting server hostname and port number from the user
    serverPort=int(sys.argv[1])
    Main(serverPort)
```

Comment: Could you be a bit more specific and add the whole error message and the line that produces the error?

Comment: line which throws the error is **line 37.** `sock.send((data[i]).encode())`

Comment: Are you using Python 3 or 2?

Comment: i am using python 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have opened your file as binary in your code:

```
with open(fileName,'rb') as fileRead:
    data= fileRead.read()
```

However, later you try to do some funny things. Now, this differs in Python 2 and 3.You are using Python 3, so this following block is problematic:

```
for i in range(0 ,len(data)): 
    sock.send((data[i]).encode())
```

In python 2 you would iterate over individual chars and it would work fine. However, in python 3 you are iterating over a `bytes` object, so `data[i]` will be an `int` object.

Instead you can just:

```
sock.sendall(data)
```

Also according to [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol), the HTTP-protocol assumes that the status line is followed by an empty line. That is why you do not see the error message, and will not see the file.

So, postfix your status codes with `"\n\n"`, so like: `'HTTP/1.1 404 not Found\n\n'`. The same goes for the OK-message.

Comment: @prachi No problem. If an answer solves your problem, you can thank by marking it as accepted, so that others will benefit from it too :)

Comment: oh sorry i just forgot :)... i did that now